# manage.py migrate not working properly it is migrating exisiting table

Tags: python, django, django-models, djongo

I am working in djongo and i created a new model and apply the migrations.
My newly created model is:

```
class NetworkIgnoreUsers(models.Model):
    _id = M.ObjectIdField()
    userId = models.CharField(max_length=50,blank=True,null=True)
    ignoreUserId = models.CharField(max_length=50,blank=True,null=True)
    mutualConnect = models.BigIntegerField(default=0)
    createTime = models.DateTimeField(blank=True,null=True)

class Meta:
    indexes = [
        models.Index(fields=['userId'],name='idx_network_user_id'),
        models.Index(fields=['ignoreUserId'],name='idx_network_ignore_user_id'),
        models.Index(fields=['createTime'],name='idx_post_create_time')

    ]
```

After doing

```
python manage.py makemigrations
```

The output of makemigrations is

```
- Create model NetworkIgnoreUsers
- Add field hidden to post
- Create index idx_post_hidden on field(s) hidden of model post
- Create index idx_network_user_id on field(s) userId of model networkignoreusers
- Create index idx_network_ignore_user_id on field(s) ignoreUserId of model networkignoreusers
- Create index idx_post_create_time on field(s) createTime of model networkignoreusers
```

After applying makemigrations i applied

```
python manage.py migrate
```

It is giving me the error djongo.sql2mongo.SQLDecodeError: FAILED SQL: CREATE TABLE shareactivity
Although that table has been migrated succesfully in my last migration.My latest migration file no. is 23 and inside it, It has dependenices on file n 22 and in file 22 i have that shareactivity table migration.
The shareactivity model is:

```
class ShareActivity(models.Model):
    _id = M.ObjectIdField()
    shareId = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
    userId = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
    activityId = models.CharField(max_length=50,blank=True, null=True)
    activityType = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
    parentId = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
    updateTime=models.DateTimeField(blank=True,null=True)

    class Meta:
        indexes = [
            models.Index(fields=['shareId'], name='idx_shareid'),
            models.Index(fields=['userId'], name='idx_userid'),
            models.Index(fields=['activityId'], name='idx_activityid'),
            models.Index(fields=['activityType'], name='idx_activitytype'),
            models.Index(fields=['parentId'], name='idx_parentid'),
            models.Index(fields=['updateTime'], name='idx_updatetime'),
           
            ]
```

Comment: please add your `models.py` , concerned `migrations` file and the complete traceback.

Comment: Updated the model

Comment: there is a file created under the `migrations` folder when you run the command `makemigrations`. Can you share that file alongside the complete traceback?